# How to set up cron job for queue:work on hostinger for laravel

Tags: cron, queue, laravel-10

hope you're well!  I'd like to set up a cron job to run the **php artisan queue:work** command every minute for my application on hostinger developed with laravel 10.

here is the cron job:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/u******/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/artisan schedule:run
```

and here is my app/Console/Kernel.php :

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();

        $schedule->command('queue:work --tries=3')
        ->cron('* * * * *')
        ->withoutOverlapping();
    }
```

when I click on view ouput this is what I get :

*INFO No scheduled commands are ready to run.*

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No6fk.jpg)

please help me to correct what is done wrong with code or cron job. Thank you.